# Probability of wining the dice game

Tags: probability, dice

Consider a two-player game between Alice and Bob, in which the
players take turns to roll a fair six-faced die. Alice rolls the die first.
Then Bob rolls the die and he wins if he gets the same outcome as
Alice. Otherwise, Alice rolls the die again and she wins if she gets
the same outcome as Bob. The game continues in this way, and it
terminates as soon as one player gets the same outcome as obtained
by the opponent in the previous roll of the die. The player who
succeeds in doing so first is the winner.

1. Find the probability that the game does not terminate after the
   first three rolls (two by Alice and one by Bob) of the die.
2. What is the probability that Alice will win the game?

For the first part i figured probability as 5/36. (Not sure about this)

for the second part i have no clue, I thought answer would come as a function of $n$ and then we can take infinite sum of that, but this will not work.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: In the first part, it looks like you calculated the probability that Alice will win on her second roll rather than the probability that neither Alice nor Bob will win within the first three rolls.  Please edit your question to explain your calculation.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  There's no reason at all that the infinite sum you propose wouldn't work, it's just a geometric series.  To be sure, there are other ways to solve the problem but your idea works just fine.